# Regular Expression to remove specific word from a string

Tags: regex, uipath

I want to remove Specific words with dot and without dot like (Pvt. ,Ltd. ,Pvt ,Ltd ,Pte. ,Pte ,Co., Co, Private Limited, Inc. , Incorporated) from the string and it should capture rest of the data available.

I have tried using

```
"\(|\)|-|\.|Pvt|Ltd|Incorporated|Pte|Inc|Co|Private|\s"
```

but it's not working.

Example text:

```
0.5Bn FinHealth Pvt. Ltd.Inc. Pte.Co.Private Limited Incorporated,
0.5Bn FinHealth Ltd.,
1MG Technologies Pvt. Ltd.,
```

I need help to improve the regex.

Comment: The [tag:uipath] tag did not seem to make sense here. Please do [edit] to indicate which regex tool or platform you are trying to use.

Comment: @tripleee UiPath is exactly the name of the tool.

Comment: My bad, I guess the tag info needs to be clarified then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe give the following pattern a try:

```
(?:\s*\b(?:(?:Pvt|Ltd|Pte|Co)\.?|Inc\.|Incorporated|Private Limited))+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fNjHeq/1)

- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group;

  - `\s*` - 0+ (Greedy) whitespace characters;
  - `\b` - A word-boundary;
  - `(?:` - Open a nested 2nd non-capture group;

    - `(?:Pvt|Ltd|Pte|Co)` - A 3rd nested non-capture group with the alternatives that can have optional dot behind;
    - `\.?` - An optional literal dot;
    - `|` - Or;
    - `Inc\.` - Literally match 'Inc.';
    - `|` - Or;
    - `Incorporated` - Literally match 'Incorporated';
    - `|` - Or;
    - `Private Limited` - Literally match 'Private Limited';
    - `))+` - Close non-capture groups and match the 1st one 1+ times.

Replace matches with empty string.

Note: I was unsure what you meant to do with `\(|\)|-|\.` but my guess is you want to replace certain stand-alone characters. If so, you can include a character-class, for example: `[().-]+` to replace these in another alternation.